# I want to upload file to S3 of AWS by 'AWS SDK for PHP'

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cakephp-3.0, aws-sdk

I want to upload file to S3 of AWS by AWS SDK for PHP.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    require('/var/www/html/imagine/src/vendor/autoload.php');   

    use App\Controller\AppController;

    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

    use Aws\Common\Aws;
    use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

class ImagesController extends AppController {
    public function upload(){

        $client = S3Client::factory(array(
            //'profile' => 'default',
            "key" => "*******",
            "secret" => "**********",
            "region" => Aws\Common\Enum\Region::AP_NORTHEAST_1
        ));
    }
}
```

But in that case, the following error message is displayed:

```
Error: Class 'Aws\Common\Enum\Region' not found 
File /var/www/html/imagine/src/Controller/ImagesController.php
```

I use cakephp3 . I think that Aws\Common\Enum\Region don't exist in cakephp3 .

please help me.
thank you.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and just use http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/

Comment: You can also use this plugin https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage

Answer (score 0):

I see the use of `require('/var/www/html/imagine/src/vendor/autoload.php');`, this makes be think that the AWS autoloader class is not importing all the library classes. What composer command did you use to install the AWS library? Also, can we see the contents of `/var/www/html/imagine/src/vendor/autoload.php` please.